Should converts say the thirteenth blessing differently?
The thirteenth blessing of Shemoneh Esrei states:

on the righteous converts and on ourselves -- may Your compassion be aroused, Hashem, our God;

As a convert, I find saying this odd. If the converts are being distinguished from other Jews in this blessing, why am I identifying with the latter group? Could I say a modified form of the blessing (at least in individual prayer), such as 'on ourselves and the descendants of Abraham and Sarah'?

Converts are descendants of Abraham and Sarah, so that wouldn't help

As a tzaddik I have the same question.

No, you should say it the way it is written in your siddur. The chachamim were well aware that converts would be saying this at some point and there is no reason for you to feel embarrassed.

I am reminded of how we all say "ashamnu" together as a community phrased in the plural because we are all in this together, all sinners of various kinds. We may or may not be exactly tzadekim, hasidim, converts, or any other category, but we still say this bracha in the shared plural.
